# LAN between two devices not working

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, rtmfp

I have written a simple AS3 program to create a serverless P2P LAN connection between different devices. Here's the gist of it:

**Client:**

```
private function initLan():void 
    {
        //G is a class with two static variables - netConnection and netGroup
        G.netConnection = new NetConnection();
        G.netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
        G.netConnection.connect("rtmfp:");
    }

    private function setupLAN(e:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.info.code);
        switch (e.info.code)
        {
            case "NetGroup.Connect.Failed": 
            case "NetGroup.Connect.Rejected": 
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected": 
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed": 
                trace("There was a problem :/\n+" + e.info.code);
                break;

            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success": 
                trace("Setting up LAN group..");
                setupGroup();
                break;

            case "NetGroup.Connect.Success": 
                trace("LAN group successful!");

                //Start bind requests
                beginBindRequests();

                break;

            case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
                var msg:Object = e.info.message;

                if (msg.type == "BIND RESPONSE") {
                    endBindRequests(); //See beginBindRequests();
                    G.netConnection.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
                    G.netGroup.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);

                    //Connection established.
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private function setupGroup():void
    {
        var groupspec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("LAN CONNECTION");
        groupspec.postingEnabled = true;
        groupspec.routingEnabled = true;
        groupspec.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;
        groupspec.addIPMulticastAddress("225.225.0.1:30303");

        G.netGroup = new NetGroup(G.netConnection, groupspec.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
        G.netGroup.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,setupLAN);
    }

    private function beginBindRequests():void 
    {
        function requestBind():void {
            G.netGroup.sendToAllNeighbors( { type:"BIND REQUEST" } );
        }

        //Code running requestBind() until endBindRequests() is called
    }
```

**Server:**

```
private function initLAN():void
    {
        //G is a class with two static variables - netConnection and netGroup
        G.netConnection = new NetConnection();
        G.netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
        G.netConnection.connect("rtmfp:");
    }

    private function setupLAN(e:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.info.code)
        {
            case "NetGroup.Connect.Failed": 
            case "NetGroup.Connect.Rejected": 
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected": 
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed": 
                trace("There was a problem :/\n+" + e.info.code);
                break;

            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success": 
                trace("Setting up LAN group..");
                setupGroup();
                break;

            case "NetGroup.Connect.Success": 
                trace("LAN group successful!");

                //Add hot controller function
                G.netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, bindResponses);
                G.netGroup.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, bindResponses);

                G.netGroup.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
                G.netConnection.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function setupGroup():void
    {
        var groupspec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("LAN CONNECTION");
        groupspec.postingEnabled = true;
        groupspec.routingEnabled = true;
        groupspec.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;
        groupspec.addIPMulticastAddress("225.225.0.1:30303");

        G.netGroup = new NetGroup(G.netConnection,groupspec.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
        G.netGroup.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, setupLAN);
    }

    private function bindResponses(e:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        detailText.text = e.info.code;
        switch (e.info.code)
        {
            case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
                if (e.info.message.type == "BIND REQUEST")
                {
                    //Send bind response
                    G.netGroup.sendToNearest({type: "BIND RESPONSE"}, e.info.from);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

This works fine when running two instances of the compiled swfs in the same PC, but doesn't work when the client is running on, for instance, a phone (packaged with AIR - yes, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is set) and the server is running on a PC (as an AIR app as well).
Tracing `e.info.code` at `setupLan()` has shown that, when in different devices, the two instances don't even "see" each other (`NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect` is never fired).  **EDIT:** I have tested, and two PCs running the client/server AIR apps also do not see each other. 
The worst part is that the same code (albeit in a different FlashDevelop project) has once worked, showing that it works. Somehow. I'm absolutely baffled and frustrated. Help. Please.

---

PS. If possible (which I'm starting to suspect not), a solution not involving meddling with router/firewall settings would be much appreciated, as most end-users will not go to that extent to use an app. Plus, I have tested two different routers and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the computer itself, not the coding or deployment. The LAN was being created properly, just on the wrong network. Following the steps in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/610733/networking-games-cant-see-join-anyone-elses-lan-servers-unless-i-host) solved the problem.